# How should I handle fetching OAuth2 authorization status in a Next.js component?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Next.js app with a React component that needs to show a summary of whether the user has initiated an OAuth2 authorization with an external service.  The component needs to show the status of the OAuth connection as well as a button whose text will change depending on the status.  When there's no connection, it should show the user a button to "Link" the account, giving them a popup to the OAuth2 authorization URL of the external service.  If the authorization has already happened, it should offer them the option to "Unlink" the external provider, i.e. forget the OAuth authorization token.

The possible states of the connection are: (1) unlinked (initial default), (2) in progress, (3) connected, (4) error/failure.  Let's assume these can be easily queried from the user table in the database.

My question is what is the best way to structure this component?  Should the component be responsible for polling an API endpoint that returns the state from the database?  Should the state from the database be queried in getServerSideProps of the page component and passed down to the summary component as a prop?  Should I be looking at web sockets or long polling?  What is the Next.js best practice for handling a use case like this?

So far, I've only implemented the polling solution, making the "state" of the OAuth connection available via an API endpoint.  But given that this piece of the UI needs to always present the user with the update to date status of the OAuth connection to the external service, it seems like this could be very inefficient to be polling every 3-5 seconds to check the state field.